# Xamarin forms ios Crash on start

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

On my iOS project, my app crash to start in debug , but in release it works.

Xamarin Forms : 1.3
Xamarin Forms Labs 1.2.1 Pre 2

My error :

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00016] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:543 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x000af] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:329 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:222 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.CreateValuesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, INode parentNode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Attempting to JIT compile method 'Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda:MakeRun1<InviteVite.Entities.Event, System.DateTime> (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.MakeDelegate (System.Type delegateType) [0x0000d] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.47/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightLambda.cs:177 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightDelegateCreator.CreateDelegate (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StrongBox`1[] closure) [0x00000] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.47/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightDelegateCreator.cs:109 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.CreateDelegateInstruction.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00043] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.47/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/Instructions/TypeOperations.cs:47 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x0001b] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.47/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/Interpreter.cs:126
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling generic value type sharing?

Go to the iOS project's options, iOS Build section.  On the Advanced tab check:  "Enable generic value type sharing".